# Tasker best profiles to trigger two states

Tags: tasker

I use some confuse profiles to trigger a task when I come to office and when I'm back  in home, based in time of the day and week(this is the problem to have many profiles). But I have two access points (wifi), in my house and in my office. So I would like to make only one or two, or even 3 profiles to this, based in the two wifi acess points, and not 6 I have right now.
Any suggestions would by welcome.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Wifi's SSID & MAC address as a trigger.

When you create your profile you'll go to state and select Wifi Connected.Then you'll see a magnifying glass next to SSID & MAC. Touching the magnifying glass will allow you to see the wifi networks currently in your area. You can add multiple SSID for a single task but then I'm not sure how the MAC addresses with interact with that. You might be able to see the wifi network it remembers but I'm not 100% sure on that. After selecting the correct SSID and its corresponding MAC Address tasker now knows to trigger. By selecting the SSID and MAC Address is prevents tasker from triggering if you connect to another wifi address with the same SSID. I hope this help. Since I'm new and trying to build up rep please don't forget to select this as your answer if it works for you and to upvote it. Thanks. If you have any issues please come back and ask more question but provide more info about the phone, Android version and tasker version along with any other plugin you might have.